# Google Maps for Xamarin

Tags: google-maps, xamarin

Google maps is not working on my emulator.
I'm using genymotion.
I've already installed google play services on emulator.

And generated application key as showed in this link:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/obtaining_a_google_maps_api_key/

[image: Figure 1]

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml file with maps permission and application key

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.movangoapp.app" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

  <application android:label="Movango.Android" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDt9ZFPajQezW24jiSbXch8ed_ontRDtjs" />
    <!--<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyDt9ZFPajQezW24jiSbXch8ed_ontRDtjs" />-->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

But maps still don't appear on emulator.